# Buddypress permalink from sub.example.com to sub

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

When i add this code `<?php bp_blog_permalink(); ?>` it display :- https://mysite.example.com/

I want to display only mysite and remove example.com.

Comment: Describe fully your install. What and how installed, which versions etc. Where BuddyPress is activated, are there domain mapping plugin(s)?

Comment: I'm using Wordpress multisite using the latest wordpress and latest buddypress...

Comment: Where BuddyPress is activated, are there domain mapping plugin(s)?

Comment: Buddypress is activated on the main website.. no there are not domain mapping plugin...

Comment: It won't work that way. You need to activated domain mapping plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/